# Javascript replace() method not working

Tags: javascript

I have this URL :

> http://example.com/example/sample/example.jpg

I want to have this :

> http:\ /\ /example.com\ /example\ /sample\ /example.jpg

```
I wrote this code : 
function addslashes(str) {
  return str.replace('/', '\/');
}

var url = http://example.com/example/sample/example.jpg
var t = addslashes(url);
alert(t);
```

As an alert, I still get the old URL. What's wrong with this code?
Thanks.

Comment: Try `.replace(/\//g,'\\/')`

Comment: Test: `'\/' === '/'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to print `\` you must escape it with another backslash.

```
function addslashes(str) {
  return str.replace(/\//g, '\\/');
}
```

Also, if you want the `replace` function to replace all occurrences, you must pass a regex with a `g` modifier instead of a string. If you pass a string it will only replace the first match and then end but with the modifier it will find all matches.

Comment: You also need the regex `/\//g` to match all slashes, not just the first.

Answer (score 1):

try this code [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o0v4ws6b/):

```
function addslashes(str) {
  return str.replace(/\//g, '\\/');
}
```

you need to add the g to set it to global, to replace all the '/' and in the replacing string you need to add '\'.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add an additinal backslash to escape it right.

With `replace` you would only replace the first match. You can also use Regular expression as you can see on the other posts. But you can also use it with simple `split` and `join` functions

```
function addslashes(url) {
    url.split('/').join('\\/');
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/daym8k4g/)**